# Suppose a channel where 0 or 1 is sent, what is probability 1 was sent given 1 was received?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, conditional-probability

I have the following probability.

> probability a $0$ is sent is $0.4$
>
> probability a $1$ is sent is $0.6$
>
> probability that due to noise, a $0$ is changed to a $1$ during transmission is $0.2$
>
> probability that due to noise, a $1$ is changed to a $0$ during transmission is $0.1$

Here is what I think should be the solution:
Let $A$ be $1$ was received, $B$ be $1$ was sent

$P(B) = 0.6$

$P(A|B) = 0.6 * 0.9 = 0.54$

$P(A) = 0.6 * 0.9 + 0.4 * 0.2 = 0.62$

Thus using $$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$$

$P(B|A) = 52.26%$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. $P(A | B) = 0.9$; what you wrote above is actually $P(A \cap B)$. Everything else looks fine, so you should end up with $P(B \mid A) = \frac{0.9(0.6)}{0.62} \approx 0.87$.